# triggering Jquery UI accordion event

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery

I have been trying to make this code work but I can't figure out how to make the Accordion event to be triggered.

Here is the code

```
$('.acc-f').accordion({
        header: '.toggler',
        event: 'click',
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });

$("map > area").click(function(){
        var getAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#"+getAnchor+"").trigger('click');
});
```

The selector connected to the .trigger() is the header

Comment: Do the element(s) that are triggering the click have the `.acc-f` class?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the heading, you need to use the 'active' option of the accordion widget and pass it the index of the heading you want to open (remember the index of the first heading is 0).

ex. 
`$('.acc-f').accordion('option', 'active', index-of-el-to-open);`

Try this:

```
   $("map > area").click(function(){
        var id = $("this").attr("href");
        index = $(".selector-for-your-headings").index(id);
        $(".acc-f").accordion("option", "active", index);

    });
```